# How can I create my own custom Hint for a specific control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to create a custom hint window (with it's own color and layout) for a specific control (not the entire application)

The hint text itself will not be connected to that specific `Hint` property control.

As suggested I wrote a handler for `CM_HINTSHOW` (This worked if the Control has `ShowHint=True`):

```
procedure TMyControl.CMHintShow(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Form1.caption := 'x';
  // Here I will display my own Hint window 
  // inherited;
end;
```

But now, how do I know when/where to **hide** it when the hint times out? neither `CM_HINTSHOW` or `CM_HINTSHOWPAUSE` gives me this info.

Comment: Write a handler for the `CM_HINTSHOW` message for that control.

Comment: Which part of this task do you need help with?

Comment: @TLama, Tahnk you. It works ok if I have the "ShowHint" property set. but now, how do I hide it when the hint times out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `CM_HINTSHOW` message handler, you can cast the `lParam` value to a `PHintInfo` pointer and then customize its fields as needed.  For instance, to simply change the background color, set the `THintInfo.HintColor` field.  To change the layout of the hint, you can derive a new class from `THintWindow` and assign that class type to the `THintInfo.HintWindowClass` field.

Let the VCL manage the hint for you, including showing and hiding it.

Comment: I need to show Unicode text on the new Hint Window + Image. I don't think I can simply derive a class `THintWindow` because the `ActivateHint` excepts `AHint: String` (AnsiString)

Comment: The VCL calls `THintWindow.ActivateHintData()` when activating a hint, so you can use the `THintInfo.HintData` field to pass custom data to the hint, such as your Unicode text.

Comment: Seem this is the right way. Can I assigned anything to back to `HintData`?

Comment: Yes, it is just a raw `Pointer` that is passed as-is, so you can assign whatever you want to it.

Comment: Will i also need to keep a reference to that Data in the `TMyHintWindow` if I later want to use it in `TMyHintWindow.Paint` for example? Also, should I return `Message.Result := 1` and `inherited'?

Comment: @zig: Yes, you will have to keep a reference to the data if you need to continue accessing it after `ActivateHintData()` has exited. Returning any value *other than* 0 for `CM_HINTSHOW` will cancel the hint. If you call `inherited`, that gives the base control code a chance to accept/reject/customize the hint, such as formatting the `HintStr` when a `TAction` is assigned to the control. So you could call `inherited` first, and then do your customizations if `Message.Result` is still 0.